# unzip sub directories into one directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, unzip

I have one directory with many sub directories 1,2 and more levels deep with zip files.

Could you help me with command to unpack all the zip files in the subdirectories into one directory named /set/ ?

I am on Ubuntu

Comment: I do not know why this is not working.  Just help comes out..
"find . -name "*.zip" | while read filename; do unzip -o -d set; done;"

Comment: StackOverflow is about helping people fix their programming code. What you have included might be considered code, so please learn to properly form your question with problem code in the body of the Q , not as a comment.Requests for tutorials, research, recommendations, and code are off-topic.  ***Please*** read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Use this from the parent directory to extratc all zip file to /set:

```
find . -name "*.zip" -print | xargs -I{} unzip -o {} -d /path/to/set
```

If you want no subdirectories in /set, you can use this from /set parent directory:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -type f  -print0 | xargs -I{} mv {} /path/to/set
```

Comment: Thank you but in that way files which were 2 or 3 levels deep still end up in respective subdirectories. In my destination folder I want only extracted files without them being in any subdirectories.

Comment: @Lucas Added that